# Best way to Register a Login Item from a Preference Pane?

Tags: objective-c, macos, service-management, nspreferencepane

I'm trying to make a Preference Pane which registers a helper app as a login item.

I have both apps in the same project and I managed to add **helper.app** to **my.prefpane**'s App Bundle, but I can't figure out how to enable **helper.app** as a login item...

---

I tried using `SMLoginItemSetEnabled` cause it seems to be the most elegant solution - but I can't get it to work...

I get this error:

"Could not locate login item *[bundle identifier]* in the caller's bundle"

I think the problem is that this function *only* works if **helper.app** is located in the main application bundle’s `“Contents/Library/LoginItems”` directory, but the "main application" which calls this function seems to be **System Preferences.app**, and not **my.prefpane**, which contains **helper.app**. I can't write **helper.app** into **System Preferences.app**'s Bundle of course...

---

Is there a workaround for this? Could you maybe extend the functionality of the `SMLoginItemSetEnabled` function or something like that? Or should I use a completely different approach?

Edit; Is there a tag for login items? I feel like my tags are really bad..

Comment: I have the same problem. Is it possible to run a background only app that runs full time and can contain the Contents/Library/LoginItems? This could be used to launch the helper app. When opening the System Pref Pane, the background app can be launched if it is not already running.

Answer (score 1):

OP here

I couldn't get it to work the easy way using `SMLoginItem`, and ended up resorting to the extremely tedious method of calling the command line tool launchctl via NSTask to tell [launchd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd) to treat my helper app as a startup item.

Basically, you'll need to create and maintain a helper.launchd.plist in an appropriate library folder ([appropriate folders](https://www.launchd.info)) which contains the path to the executable of your helper app and some other configurations most importantly `KeepAlive` which will tell launchd to automatically reopen your app should it ever crash or be closed by the user, and `RunAtLoad` which will lead to your app to be started at login. [This is what my helper.launchd.plist looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsLH7.png)

You can then register your helper app via the terminal with the commands:

```
launchctl bootstrap gui/$UID [path to your helper.launchd.plist]
```

to activate your helper as login item

and

```
launchctl bootout gui/$UID [path to your helper.launchd.plist]
```

to deactivate your helper as a login item.

You can use these terminal commands from within your code. I did it using NSTask, but I think there might be better ways of doing it.

---

Note that $UID is an `internal variable`, which the terminal automatically expands into the user id of the current user before it feeds the gui/$UID argument to the launchctl command line tool. My UID is 501, so launchctl actually gets the input "gui/501", not "gui/$UID". I use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"gui/%d", geteuid()]` to create an appropriate user domain argument for launchctl with Objective-C.

---

Random tips:

- Note that the my.prefpane can be in different locations depending on
  whether the prefpane is installed for all or just for a specific
  user.
- I recommend you put a helper.launchd.plist template into your
  project. Then you only have to edit the `Program` field depending on
  the user and where the prefpane is installed and not create the whole
  plist file programmatically.
- I put my helper.launchd.plist into
  /Users/[User]/Library/LaunchAgents and I have noticed, that that
  folder does not exist on a fresh install, so you might have to check
  whether the library folder supposed to contain your helper.launchd.plist actually exists and create it if necessary.
- Apple rewrote launchctl in macOS 10.10 Yosemite, they added `launchctl bootstrap` and `launchctl bootout` as replacements for the now deprecated `launchctl load` and `launchctl unload`. If you want to be backwards compatible you might have to fallback to `load` and `unload` on older versions of macOS

Hope this helps and good luck with your project!

Comment: oh man, I've just come down the same path updating my popular extension Cursorcerer to work cleanly in Mojave/Catalina and had the same problem with SMLoginItemSetEnabled()... I can't believe Apple no longer has a simple way to do this for developers that make PreferencePanes... This is going to be a terrible headache, but thank you for going through this and posting.